# Problems updating RVM to upgrade to ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am trying to upgrade to ruby 2.0.0 and I am running into problems getting rvm updated:

Here is my first error trying to update to ruby-2.0.0[-p353]:

```
Error running 'requirements_smf_update_system ruby-2.0.0[-p353]',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1385828966_ruby-2.0.0[-p353]/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

So I tried:

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

And got the following warnings:

```
Can not update 'scripts/extras/completion.zsh/_rvm', it's a conflict between Zsh 
and multiuser installation, prefix the command with 'rvmsudo' to update this file.
```

but it alerted that install was complete.  When I run:

```
rvm usge:
```

I get this warning:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin' is not
at first place, usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for
'PATH=...' entries, it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 
'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles', to fix temporarily in this shell session run:
'rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194'
```

And I'm going in a circle. I would like to read:

```
/usr/local/rvm/log/1385828966_ruby-2.0.0[-p353]/update_system.log
```

but I don't know where to find it. I must have accidentally set up rvm with multiuser instead of single user but I can't be sure because I used to tutorial to set is up.
Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which tutorial did you use?  rvm.io states, paraphrased "tutorials, Blogs, are cool.  And sometimes right.  But this instruction is the only that is supposed".  How did you install.  You should be able to do `rvm implode` as sudo or root and blow it away.  Then follow the instructions on the official site.

Comment: I used Michael Hartl's tutorial.  I considered 'rvm implode' but was afraid.  I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ruby-2.0.0[-p353]` the brackets `[]` mean optional so you can either write:

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0
```

OR:

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p353
```